# Are Angular's promises asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I may have miss something about Angular's promises but I was wondering something : are promises asynchronous ? I'm not sure if 'asynchronous' is the right word but let me explain myself.

In my code I use promises to do a really big process (read and write hundreds of big files) while I display a loading bar to watch the progress of the process. I've noticed that even if my code is in a promise, it seems to not really be asynchronous and freeze the display (that I assume is manage by the main thread).

For example in the code bellow that you can find in this [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NYM95NTQOvnajR5Bcbfu?p=preview), I'm wondering how to let the progress bar move while the big process is done. I understand why it's freezing when I call it in the main thread but not when I'm using Angular's promises.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
  
  function hugeProcess () {
    var i = 0;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (i++ < 100000) {
      console.log(i);
    }
    var end = new Date().getTime();
      var time = end - start;
      $scope.processTime = 'Done in ' + time  + 'ms';
  }
  
  $scope.onClickStartHugeProcess = function () {
    console.log('onClickStartHugeProcess');
    hugeProcess();
  };
  
  $scope.onClickStartHugeProcessWithPromise = function () {
    console.log('onClickStartHugeProcessWithPromise');
    $q.when()
    .then(function () {
      return hugeProcess();
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is "multi-threaded" and the answer is no, all js runs in a single thread.

Comment: @georg: No, all JS does not run on a single thread. Not even on browsers. There is one *main UI thread*, however; if you want another thread, you have to create one explicitly via web workers.

Comment: You should check out web workers for running CPU bound stuff on a separate thread and keeping your UI responsive.

Comment: `when()` with no argument doesn't do anything..and process doesn't return anything either

Comment: I don't think you're using promises right - a `then` callback gets run after a promise has resolved, and calling `$q.when()` without an argument just creates an immediately resolved promise. So effectively you're just instantly running `hugeProcess`, rather than resolving after it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that your `hugeProcess` function never yields. So yes, it's called asynchronously (`then` callbacks are always called asynchronously in a Promises/A+ promise implementation), but that doesn't change what `hugeProcess` is doing when it gets called, which is hogging the main UI thread such that nothing else can happen while it's running. There's only one main UI thread, and all of your JavaScript runs on that one main UI thread except [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/).

To make `hugeProcess` not do that, you have to break it up and have it call itself after a brief delay, via `setTimeout` (or perhaps something built into Angular).

As [Joe Clay points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672031/are-angulars-promises-asynchronous/35672116#comment59023220_35672031), this code doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
$q.when()
.then(function () {
  return hugeProcess();
});
```

That's effectively:

```
setTimeout(hugeProcess, 0);
```

...since `$q.when()` with no arguments returns a resolved promise, and adding a `then` callback to a resolved promise just results in your callback being called as soon as possible (but asynchronously; e.g., `then` returns before the callback is called).

Comment: I've updated my Plnkr with the code below and now the hugeProcess return the time of processing but it still the same problem.

I will look at web workers.

Thanks.

`$scope.onClickStartHugeProcessWithPromise = function () {
    console.log('onClickStartHugeProcessWithPromise');
    $q(hugeProcess)
    .then(function (time) {
      $scope.processTime = 'Done in ' + time  + 'ms';
    });
  };`

Comment: In AngularJS use the `$timeout` service instead of the raw `setTimeout` function. The `$timeout` service returns promises and is integrated with the AngularJS framework digest cycle. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: @georgeawg: Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've discover Web Workers and here is a first version of my code using them.

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {

  function hugeProcess () {
    var i = 0;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (i++ < 100000) {
      console.log(i);
    }
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    postMessage(time);
  }

  var blob = new Blob(["onmessage = " + hugeProcess.toString()]);

  // Obtain a blob URL reference to our worker 'file'.
  var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var worker = new Worker(blobURL);

  worker.onmessage = function (message) {
    $scope.processTime = 'Done in ' + message.data  + 'ms';
    $scope.$apply()
  };

  $scope.onClickStartHugeProcessWithPromise = function () {
    console.debug('onClickStartHugeProcessWithPromise');
    $q(function () {
      worker.postMessage(''); // Start the worker.
    });
  };
});
```

I don't think I'm using right but it does what I want ... I've found the package [ng-webworker](https://github.com/mattslocum/ng-webworker) for Angular that seems to mix promises and web workers so that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Web Worker is right solution. I had similar problem and developed angular plugin [ng-vkThread](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/ng-vkthread) to simplify such kind of tasks.

Basic usage is:

```
/* function to execute in a thread */
function foo(n, m){ 
    return n + m;
}

/* create an object, which you pass to vkThread as an argument*/
var param = {
   fn: foo      // <-- function to execute
   args: [1, 2] // <-- arguments for this function
};

/* run thread */
vkThread.exec(param).then(
   function (data) {
       console.log(data);  // <-- thread returns 3 
    },
    function(err) {
        alert(err);  // <-- thread returns error message
    }

);
```

[Live demo](http://www.eslinstructor.net/ng-vkthread/demo/)

--Vadim